# Indexes and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=D(0,1)$.
Let $f\in \mathcal{O}( D), f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$

Let $N(\omega)= \int_{\partial D(0,\frac{1}{6})} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z) - \omega } dz$ defined for $w\in D(0,\frac{1}{12})$

I need to show that $f(D)$ contains $ D(0,\frac{1}{12})$.

What I did:

I showed that $N(w)$ is the index of $f(\partial D(0,\frac{1}{6})) $ related to $w$.

Remains to prove that $N(w) \neq 0$ so that any $w\in  D(0,\frac{1}{12})$ is inside the loop  $ f(\partial D(0,\frac{1}{6})) \subset  f(D)$

So by connexity of the index function in connected spaces we should have $N(w)=N(0)$, remains to show that $0\in f(D(0,\frac{1}{6}))$ but I am not even sure if this is true.

Many thanks.

Comment: Regarding the last "remains to":  from the first line, "$f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Right! But I have to prove that $f(D(0,\frac{1}{6})$ is not a closed set but I didn't manage to prove it, otherwise $0=f(0) $ might be in the boundaries of $f(D(0,\frac{1}{6}))$

Comment: $D(0,1/6)$ contains an open set containing $0$. and $f$ maps that open set non-constantly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: there is an open $V \subset D(0,\frac{1}{6} )$ such that $0\in V$ and  $f^{-1}(V) \subset D(0,\frac{1}{6} )$ so 0 is inside the open $f(f^{-1}(V) )=V $?

Comment: Not quite.  Apply the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) to a neighborhood of $0$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Now I understand thank you !